# What permissions are needed on the tmux.conf file

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, configuration, tmux

I have my dotfiles on GitHub. My `tmux.conf` sits in `~/code/.dotfiles/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`.

In my `~/.config` I have an alias, like so:

```
lrwxrwxrwx    42 j j  2 Feb 11:00  tmux -> /home/j/code/.dotfiles/.config/tmux
```

The permissions on the actual `.conf` file are:

```
~ ❯ l ~/.config/tmux     
Permissions Size User     Group    Date Modified Name
.rw-rw-r--   142 j        j        8 Mar 09:44   tmux.conf
```

When I run `tmux` my options aren't being read. I know because in my config I have:

```
# rename of windows
set -g allow-rename off
```

But in `tmux` when I run:

```
tmux show-options -gw
```

I can see that `allow-rename` is `on`

I think it might be a permissions issue, but I'm not sure what permissions I need to have.

Answer (score 0):

My `.tmux.conf` has a `644 (.rw-r--r--)` permission, but it should work with  your permissions

The issue is that you need to manually tell `tmux` to source your config file

Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd> :

```
source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

After killing the tmux server (same key combination but you enter `kill-server`) and relaunching it, you will see your config applied

Comment: Oh! How come? Why must I manually tell `tmux` to source the config file? The config file [according to Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/tmux#Configuration) already sits in a location where `tmux` is supposed to be looking?

Comment: Actually, *in most cases*, tmux is likely to source its config at server cold start @J86, like expected, but in some cases it will not (with no warning/explaination). Sourcing the config manually is a way to know that the server sourced correctly the file